# Make the Font of Chapter Number the Same as Chapter Title

Tags: chapters, titlesec, report

I want my chapter number to be the same as the chapter number. [image: Here is MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\makeatletter%%Here is the counter introduced
\def\numinwords#1{\expandafter\@numinwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@numinwords#1{%
    \ifcase#1\or ONE\or TWO\or THREE\or FOUR\or FIVE\or SIX\or SEVEN\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\makeatother
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% the below format chapter header
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}% chapter font size
{\filcenter{\MakeUppercase{\textls[400]
            {\chaptertitlename}}\ \numinwords{chapter}}}{20pt}{\LARGE}% % chapter TITLE name font size
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\title{}
\author
{}

\date{}
\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    
    
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    %\input{Chapters/Introduction}
    ...........
    \chapter{Conclusion}
    %\input{Chapters/Conclusion}
    \chapter{Reference}
    %\input{Chapters/Reference}
    
\end{document}
```

**What I Want**

1. I want `CHAPTER ...` to have the same font as the chapter title.
2. I want the `vspace` between the two to close slightly.

Comment: If you don't want uppercase, don't use `\MakeUppercase`? And if you don't letter spacing, don't use `\textsl`. You should also read the description of `\titleformat` in the the `titlesec` user manual.

Comment: Your comment brings a solution to my `first` item.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `\titleformat` on page 4 of the `titlesec` user manual, i.e., the meaning of the `<sep>` argument?

Comment: Yes, I have read it; your comment has also solved my second item.